# Adding an onclick button corresponding to my JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an html table which will be blank and will have values being input by the user. When the values have been input, I have one cell of the table which will be showing the result of the formula function that I have created in Jquery. My formulas work fine when I already input the values; however, when I try to have an input field and run the code, my submit button on onclick doesn't work. Can someone please tell me how do I create a submit button? I am pasting my JQuery code below.

```
    $("td[formula]").each(function mathfunction() {
  //1 get formula attribute
  var formula = $(this).attr('formula');

  //2 use regex to make expression, with the surpport of "A122"， "AB1" and more
  var expression = formula.replace(/([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/g, "parseFloat(\$('#$1').html())");

  //3 eval the expression
  var result = eval(expression);

  //4 set the value
  $(this).html(result);

});
```

My JSFiddle Link is in the comments section.

Comment: You need to wrap the code you have in a function that gets called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you create an example of your problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dEpEaPdTt3 Here is the link

Comment: I can't see anything on your fiddle - it appears blank @Shellz

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to wrap your jQuery event(s) in.

```
function thisButtonClick(){
    //All of your code above goes here.

}
```

On your button (in the html) you can use `onclick="thisButtonClick()"` and this will execute all of your code.